# How to use SharedPreferences as LocalStore, in more generic way?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Being new in Android world and advancing with joy day by day ;)
I would like to share examples about common usage.

Here comes example about using SharedPreferences with generic LocalStore class.

create a common class to be used by your main activity or by any of sub-activity.

```
    public class LocalStore {

        private static final String TAG = "LocalStore";
        private static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "userprefs";

        public static void clear(Context context) {
            clear(context, "unknown");
        }
        public static void clear(Context context, String caller) {
            Editor editor = 
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            Log.d(TAG, "caller:"+caller + "|clear LocalStore");
        }

        public static boolean setCustomBooleanData(String key, boolean value, Context context) {
        Editor editor =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);

        return editor.commit(); 
    }
    public static boolean getCustomBooleanData(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return (savedSession.getBoolean(key, false));
    }

    public static boolean setCustomStringData(String key, String value, Context context) {
        Editor editor =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);

        return editor.commit(); 
    }
    public static String getCustomStringData(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return (savedSession.getString(key, null));
    }


    public static boolean isCustomStringExistInLocal(String customKey, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return (savedSession.getString(customKey, null))==null?false:true;
    }

public static boolean saveObject(String objKey, Serializable dataObj, Context context) {
        Editor editor =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(objKey, ObjectSerializer.serialize(dataObj) );

        Log.d(TAG, "savedObject| objKey:"+objKey+"/" + dataObj.toString());

        return editor.commit(); 
    }
    public static Object getObject(String objKey, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Object dataObj = ObjectSerializer.deserialize(savedSession.getString(objKey, null));

        return dataObj;
    }

    }
```

Note: You can use ObjectSerializer from [here](http://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)

Enjoy!

Additional update: 
I implemented a library to use MEMDISKCACHE and SHAREDPREF as GENERIC_STORE
anyone interested can use it from
-> https://github.com/wareninja/generic-store-for-android

Comment: StackOverflow FAQ says: " It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: Could you please make this a proper question and answer instead of everything being in the question body. Otherwise it may get deleted.

Comment: It is nice of you to share :) , but I think this belongs in a blog rather than a question and answer site.

Comment: you should have posted the ObjectSerializer class too

Comment: @adi ObjectSerializer is reused from Apache library, link is included in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want some tips on how to improve it even more, here you go.

- Usually Android follows a convention to keep the `Context` variable as the first parameter. It is good practice to do this when creating any general library.
- If you want to make it more generic, why not try method overloading? It will give the developer more flexibility when setting values much like how extras are handled in the `Intent` class.

For example:

```
public static boolean setData(Context, String key, boolean value) {
        Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        return editor.commit(); 
    }
public static boolean setData(Context, String key, String value) {
        Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        return editor.commit(); 
    }
```

So you can simply call the overloaded functions like this:

```
setData(this, "myBoolean", true);
setData(this, "myString", "Its Awesome");
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
 fun <T> putData(key: String?, item: T) {
        val editor = localSharedPreferences.edit()
        val list = gson.toJson(item)
        editor.putString(key, list)
        editor.apply()
    }
```