# store Array in sharedpreferences

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences, persistent

I have an `Array` with integer values. It will grow over time. It will have approximately up to 50 values.
I want to store the array persistent and thus I thought about storing it in `SharedPreferences`.
I know that no complex types can be stored in it, but I also heard about to serialise the `Array` and then store it in `SharedPreferences`.
Can someone give me a hint or even better sample code how to do that?

Comment: You can also refer to this [ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175880/how-can-i-store-an-integer-array-in-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very efficient way, but will get the job done:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
final int count = 50;
final String KEY_COUNT = "COUNT";
final String KEY_VAL_PREFIX = "VAL_";
int values[] = new int[count];

/*
 * ... put some stuff in values[] ...
 */

final Editor sped = prefs.edit();
sped.putInt(KEY_COUNT, count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    sped.putInt(KEY_VAL_PREFIX + i, values[i]);
}
sped.commit();
```

Then later you can retrieve these values by grabbing the KEY_COUNT value from the prefs, then filling your empty array with `values2[i] = getInt(KEY_VAL_PREFIX + i, 0)` calls.

Comment: :Do you think you can help me with this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209673/using-preferences-my-listview-is-empty-cant-store-data

Comment: @Josh can you include the whole code for the getter and setter?

Answer (score 1):

You may use ObjectSerializer to do it. Here is SO discussion on how to do.[Store Shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064901/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-as-localstore-in-more-generic-way)

Answer (score 1):

I would convert your array to a string of values separated by commas. And then store the string as a single key-value pair.

Then, when you want to extract the array, simple use the split function to split the string up into array elements based on a comma separator.