# using preferences --  my listview is empty (can't store data)

Tags: android, preferences

I need  help in order to properly set up preferences.

I have my main activity from which by pressing the menu button ,i am going to the preferences activity.There,i have 3 entries where the user inputs his data.The first entry is a serial number.

I want to be able to show a list with all the serial numbers and when the user selects one,show him the other entries (or do some calculations ).

----------UPDATED------------------------------------

My main activity is:

```
 public class Strength extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{


View goto_list;
SharedPreferences mypref;
String [] values=new String [100];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Set up click listeners
    goto_list=(View) findViewById(R.id.goto_list);
    goto_list.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Setup preferences
    mypref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditr=mypref.edit();

    final Integer counter =values.length; 
    prefsEditr.putInt("size", counter);
    for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
        prefsEditr.putString("serial_number"+i, values[i]);
    }

    prefsEditr.putString("date", "");
    prefsEditr.putString("strength", "1.0");
    prefsEditr.commit();     

}
```

My goto_list activity which will show the listview with the serial numbers:

```
   public class goto_list extends ListActivity {
private final String TAG="list";
SharedPreferences mypref;
    String[] listItems = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);


    mypref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    final Integer counter = mypref.getInt("size",0); 
    listItems=new String[counter];
    for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
        listItems[i] = mypref.getString("serial_number"+i, "");
    }

   //what to do with ArrayAdapter? 
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);              
   setListAdapter(adapter);
}
       protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "position: " + position);
        Log.i(TAG, "item: " + listItems[position]);
        mypref.edit().putString("serial_number", listItems[position]).commit();

    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent i=new Intent(this,calcs_strength.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```

So, my problem is that the listview is empty.It show no data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
SharedPreferences mypref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditr=mypref.edit();
prefsEditr.putString("username", username);
prefsEditr.commit();

username = mypref.getString("username", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

1): In `prefsEditr.putFloat("strength", -1);` the value "-1" is an Integer and therefore stored as an Integer. You could use `Float.parseFloat` to parse an Integer (eg parsing the stored Integer value or parsing an Integer value and store it).

Can you please elaborate 2) and 3)? I did not get what *exactly* you meant.

/edit: Some sample code for saving / reading an array

```
public String[] readArray() {
    SharedPreferences openPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("arrayfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Integer counter = openPreferences.getInt("size", 0);
    String[] result = new String[counter];
    for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
        result[i] = openPreferences.getString("entry_"+i, "");
    }
    return result;
}

public void writeArray(String[] array) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("arrayfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    final Integer counter =array.length; 
    editor.putInt("size", counter);
    for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
        editor.putString("entry_"+i, array[i]);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

/edit: Also use a `PreferenceActivity` instead of a `ListActivity`. That makes things easier.

Then add this code in `OnCreate()`:

```
    PreferenceManager localPreferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
    localPreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesName("main_prefs");
    localPreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_PRIVATE);
            [for every entry do:] {
                addNewPref("ArrayValue"); 
            }
```

and then add dynamically Preference Views to the Activity, just adjust the code below:

```
 private void addNewPref(String title) {
    Preference newPref = new Preference(this);
    newPref.setTitle(title);
    ((PreferenceScreen) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("category_key")).addItemFromInflater(newPref);
}
```

Content of the `PreferenceScreen` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:key="category_key" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: :Hello,1) i did "putFloat("strength", -1.0f)" but still the same..As for (2) i am asking this.the user enters some input.How can i use that input?(for example he inputs "serial_number".How i will use this value in my application?That's why i am trying to do "String serial_number = mypref.getString("serial_number", "");" but i am not sure..As for (3) in the code above (the last one) ,i want to put in the 'String values' all the values(serial_number) from user input,in order to show them in a list.Finally,check comments inside "protected void onListItemClick.." at the same code(last).Thank

Comment: To read out / write values from / to SharedPreferences, create a new SharedPreferences object, here's a tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html
This should answer 2) and 3) :)

Comment: Also have a look at the developers page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Well if you want to store an array into a SharedPreference, you need first an Integer stored, that saves the array's size. Then you need to store every entry in the SharedPreference with a different key, eg entry 14 is saved as "my_list_14". To load the data, first load the counter and then load every entry from "my_list_0" to "my_list_COUNTER"

Comment: I edited my answer and put some sample code how to store/read an array. Although I haven't tried it, but it should work

Comment: Can you please upload the complete source code somewhere? Then it would be much easier to solve the problem...

Comment: Try using a PreferenceActivity instead of a ListActivity. See my updated answer.

Comment: Just replace the `LongclickPreference` with `Preference` and modify the constructor.

Comment: Updated the answer. But you should **really** have a close look at the SharedPreferences documentation!

Comment: :After you corrected me about the float,the only thing that i had problem was that the "serial_number" should be an array in order to show every entry in a listview.I appreciate your help but i got confused from there.I think we complexed it a lot.I don't understand the last things that you sayed.I am totally lost.Again,i appreciate your help but either i am not understanding well either you are giving me more complicated things than it requires.That's why i told you to correct me on my code if you could.I updated but i don't know what to do.I just want to pass an array  (serial_number)

Comment: So, do you want to pass the array to the application or do you want to store the array permanently?

Comment: :I want to store the array in order for the user to retrieve the values whenever he wants.When i say to "pass" i mean retrieve the user input to the listview(which will have all serial nu,bers in a list).Do you want me to edit my post and remove all the things you tried?(in order to be more simple)

Comment: @George How much of the comment thread can be deleted?  It's getting a little out of hand.  Some of this should be edited back into the question/answer.

Comment: @Force How much of the comment thread can be deleted?  It's getting a little out of hand.  Some of this should be edited back into the question/answer.

Comment: @Force:I edited my post.I left the "final Integer counter = mypref.getInt("size", 0);
        String [] values=new String[counter];..." things you told me,but i don't know if i am using them right.I want to create an array String [] values which will hold all the entries for "serial_number" and thn use "values" in the arrayadapter.

Comment: @Force:I forgot to mention that i have 3 fields, serial_number,date and strength.But i want only the serial_number  entries to show on the listview

Comment: @Force:Hello,did you understand what i want to do?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems like you're able to pass the serial numbers over to your list activity, and they show up in the list, right?  And now you're wondering what to do with the adapter?

If so, then you just need to override onListItemClick, pull the string from values[position], store that back into your preferences, and finish() the list activity.  Make sure turn that String[] into a field instead of a local var, so that you can fill it in in onCreate and use it on onListItemClick.

```
String[] listItems = null;//fill in in onCreate
SharedPreferences prefs = null;//grab in onCreate

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "position: " + position);
    Log.i(TAG, "item: " + listItems[position]);
    prefs.edit().putString("mySerial", listItems[position]).commit();
}
```

Comment: :Hello and thanks for the help.The list activity is empy.That's my problem.I updated the goto_list activity as you said,but still the same.

Comment: :Also, i am not sure if i am using String []listItems right ,because at the beginning i do "String[] listItems = new String [100];" and then (in onCreate) "String[] listItems = new String [counter];" in order to fill

Comment: You want `String[] listItems = null;` as a top level variable (called a field) at the beginning of your class, where you set other class member variables.  Then you want `listItem = ...` in your onCreate - note without the `String[]' prefix here, or that will actually create another local string array with the same name.

Comment: Here's something to try.  Forget about the preferences fetching for now.  In your onCreate, do `listItems = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"};` and pass that into your array adapter.  Do you get anything in your pop-up list?

Comment: :Yes,it works with "One,Two,Three",it shows them .But with  listItems = new String [counter]; the list is empty.Also,in the goto_list activity ,the "SharedPreferences mypref=null;" must be null or not?(either way it's not working,still the same).

Comment: Alright, what's the value of counter?  Do a `Log.i(TAG, "counter: " + counter);` after you retrieve it and make sure it isn't 0.

Comment: :the counter has value 100 .(in the first activity i have "String [] values=new String [100];") . (i did debug ,because the log.i doesn't show anything).But below counter it has a "savedInstanceState = null".

Answer (score 1):

your array is empty.

change this:

```
for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
    prefsEditr.putString("serial_number"+i, values[i]);
}
```

with:

```
for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
    // just replace the string with you serial number;
    values[i] = "998-123-234-122_" + i;
    prefsEditr.putString("serial_number"+i, values[i]);
}
```

Comment: :Hello,with this it just shows me a list with numbers 0-99.I want to show me the serial number of every entry in the list.

Comment: :I didn't mean that.I want to show me the serial number that the user had entered.My serial_number is the key  from preferences.xml.

Comment: :Hello,do you have an idea for that?Thanks!