# how to store data in shared preferences

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an arraylist and I want to save the data, when the app is closed / terminated / destroyed.

```
//Class SimpleBookManager.java is a singleton

private ArrayList<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

public Book getBook(int index){
    return allBooks.get(index);
}
public void saveChanges(){
    //Save the allBooks into memory
}
public void loadBooks(){
    //Load the allBooks into memory to the variable allBooks;
}
```

It is reached by writing `SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().saveChanges();` in all the other classes in the package.

What is the best way to implement the method saveChanges() and loadBooks()? Could you give a brief example perhaps? I have read something about shared preferences in android but unfortunately I don't quite get it =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SO question that has the code that you are looking for in it

- [Android Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences)

To store an array in shared preferences look here -

- [store Array in sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714579/store-array-in-sharedpreferences)

However, if your app has a lot of books, or a lot of information about each book it would be better to use an SQLite database

Comment: This is better as a comment since you have only linked to another question and not provider an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an instance of SharedPreferences from any context within your app.

The following code saves a preferences with key "some_pref_key, and value "some_pref_value" into a file named "your_preference_file_name"

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences( "your_preference_file_name", MODE_APPEND );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString( "some_pref_key", "some_pref_value" );
    editor.commit();
```

If you need to save other type of data, check the [SharedPreferences.editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)  documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to store a single Data not more than 10,You can use shared preferences. 
Example : If you are going to store bookid, then shared preferences is enough.

But If you are trying to store Array of Objects / data, you should store it in Database only. It is convenient for dealing with large amount of data