# How to save an array of strings with SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, arrays, string, sharedpreferences

I have an array of Strings, I need to save this array with SharedPreferences, and then read and display them on a ListView.

For now, I use this algorithm:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

//To save the strings
public void saveStrings(String[] str){
    int a = 0;
    int lenght = str.length;
    while (a<lenght){
        sp.edit().putString(Integer.toString(a), Integer.toString(str[a])).apply();
        a=a+1;
    }
}

//To read the strings
public String[] getStrings(){
    String[] str = new String [8];
    int a = 0;
    int lenght = 8; //To read 8 strings
    while (a<lenght){
        str[a] = sp.getString(Integer.toString(a),"Null");
        a=a+1;
    }
return str;
}
```

Is there a way to save and read the entire array, rather than a string at a time?

For this project I'm using API level 19 (Android 4.4.2 KitKat)

Comment: Look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064901/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-as-localstore-in-more-generic-way

Comment: Use GSON. Here is your solution:

- http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848025/1787135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use [putStringSet()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29), but (a) it's only from API level 11 onwards, and (b) as its name says, it's for **sets** (which means that you will lose the original ordering and any duplicates present in the array).

We solved this problem by "encoding" collections into a string and using `putString()` and decoding them afterwards on `getString()`, with this pair of methods (for ArrayList, but should be easily convertible into array versions):

```
public String encodeStringList(List<String> list, char separator)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list.size() * 50);

    for (String item : list)
    {
        if (sb.length() != 0)
            sb.append(separator);

        // Escape the separator character.
        sb.append(item.replace(Character.toString(separator), "\\" + separator));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public List<String> decodeStringList(String encoded, char separator)
{
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (encoded != null && encoded.length() != 0)
    {
        // Use negative look-behind with backslash, because it's used for escaping the separator.
        // Expression is "(?<!\)s" with doubling because of escaping in regex, and again because of escaping in Java).
        String splitter = "(?<!\\\\)" + separator; //$NON-NLS-1$
        String[] parts = encoded.split(splitter);

        // While converting to list, take out the escape characters used to escape the now-removed separator.
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
            items.add(parts[i].replace("\\" + separator, Character.toString(separator)));
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I understand that I can't use this method, because I have a lot of duplicates, and I can't lose the duplicates!

Comment: @Salvuccio96 In case I wasn't clear, this method does preserve duplicates, just call putString(). I was warning against putStringSet().

Answer (score 0):

`Set<String> set =list.getStringSet("key", null);
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(list of the string list u have);
editor.putStringSet("key", set);
editor.commit();`
Please refer to this thread for further details [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 0):

```
//while storing
str is string array
String fin="";
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fin=fin+str[i]+",";
}
fin=fin.substring(0,fin.length()-1);

//while retrieving
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(fin.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Comment: the split function here will see for spaces zero or more then a literal comma and then again spaces zero or more.